# Flow was not found when attempting to start Atom/Nuclide

Tags: node.js, react-native, atom-editor, flowtype, nuclide-editor

I am working on `react-native` application for which I am using `Atom` IDE. I am getting an error on opening `Atom`

[image]

I installed `babel-cli` and `babel-preset-flow` with npm command.

> npm install --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-flow

Now when I restart `Atom` then it shows same warning to me "Flow was not found when attempting to start". Can anyone help me how to fix it.

I have followed this https://medium.com/react-native-training/getting-started-with-react-native-and-flow-d40f55746809 flow server is working well but how I add flow to atom so I can get rid from this https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jJVI.png

Answer (score 32):

#### If the error itself is your concern, and you don't want to use Flow or don't even know what it does:

`Nuclide -> Settings -> Flow` and uncheck: `Warn when Flow is not found`

#### If, however, you want to use Flow:

Make sure you've got flow installed. Since flow will have to be matched with the version specified in `.flowconfig` it's a good idea to install it locally rather than globally.

For example, if your `.flowconfig` says:

```
[version]
^0.40.0
```

[Install](https://flow.org/en/docs/install/) that very version of `flow-bin` locally, i.e:

```
npm install --save-dev flow-bin@0.40.0
```

Then `Nuclide -> Settings -> Flow` and check: `Use the Flow binary included in each project's flow-bin`

In case of issues, check [flow issues](https://nuclide.io/docs/help/troubleshooting/#flow-issues).

Comment: As the author of Nuclide's Flow integration, I couldn't have said it better myself. Clear and concise. I'm bookmarking this to link from Nuclide GitHub issues.

Comment: I have followed this https://medium.com/react-native-training/getting-started-with-react-native-and-flow-d40f55746809 flow server is working well but how I add flow to atom so I can get rid from this https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jJVI.png

Comment: Dang. All this time and it was that last check box that got things going. XD Thank you!

Comment: the last step is important.

Comment: Thanks buddy... explained better than the official doc.