# How to set flow command in PATH

Tags: atom-editor, flowtype

I installed flow server and atom IDE support for flow. https://atom.io/packages/ide-flow

> If the flow command is not on your path, set its location in the package settings under Flow Path

I am on Windows system, I am not sure what path I need to set to get this working.

Answer (score 1):

To use the flow-bin installed in the projects node_modules dir, there is a setting in Nuclide:

Preferences... > Packages > nuclide > Settings > Nuclide-flow > Use the Flow binary included in each project's flow-bin

The security admonition stating "we will immediately run code" is not quite true, flow-bin seems to be executed only when you open a .js file in the editor. I guess it might be pertinent to ensure that the flow-bin is what you expecting before opening any files.

Comment: I have already checked in my atom setting. when I restart my atom, everytime I get this message https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jJVI.png see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43407149/flow-was-not-found-when-attempting-to-start-atom-nuclide

Comment: Did you also install flow-bin following the instructions on the site linked the message? When you say that the flow server is working, how are you starting that?

Comment: I am starting it after launching the atom. Do I need to run this `npm run flow` before launching atom ?

Comment: I don't need to do that. As long as npm run flow works, it seems like atom should start it for you. Sorry I can't think of anything else, sounds like you've done everything that I did to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

You can run

```
where flow
```

or maybe

```
where flow.exe
```

or

```
where flow.cmd
```

depending on how you have installed Flow. This will get you the full path to Flow.

Comment: I setup flow for my project https://medium.com/react-native-training/getting-started-with-react-native-and-flow-d40f55746809 When I am running suggested command then I am getting `INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s). `

Comment: BTW flow is my application directory D:\React Native\Scheduled\node_modules\.bin but How I can set it in PATH so atom text editor will have access of it

Comment: Ah, if you installed a project-local flow-bin then it won't be accessible on the command line so this will not work. I don't know about `ide-flow`, but if you use Nuclide instead you can just enable a setting to use the project-local flow-bin and then you won't have to specify the path to the binary yourself.

Comment: I am using Nuclide, How I can enable a setting to use project flow bin ?